# How to add a vertical line in a horizontal bar chart using primefaces + jqplot

Tags: primefaces, charts, jqplot

I'm using primefaces + jqplot to create a Horizontal and Stacked bar chart:

Code ( Example - Primefaces ):

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml

I need to add a line in chart like this image: ( Red line in Vertical )

http://peltiertech.com/Excel/pix1/AddLine.gif

Can i do this with Primefaces + Jqplot ? If it's possible, someone can help me to understand ?

Answer (score 2):

Finally solved my problem:

1 - Add a extender in Managed Bean with name of extender:

```
 horizontalBarModel.setExtender("NAME");
```

2 - Create a javascript function in xhtml:

```
function NAME(){}
```

3 - Add a Canvas Overlay:

```
function NAME()
{
 this.cfg.canvasOverlay = {
                show: true,
                objects: [{verticalLine:{
                "shadow":"false",
                "lineWidth":5,
                "color":"rgb(255,0,0)",
                "x":50 
 }}]};
```

}

4 - This vertical/horizontal lines depend on the following files (using Primefaces 5.0):

```
jqplot.canvasOverlay.js
```

You can find this file in  [Bitbucket Cleonello Jqplot](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot).

5 - Add Labels and Tooltips with: [Bitbucket Cleonello Jqplot - Support to canvas overlay lines](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/pull-request/48/add-label-support-to-canvas-overlay-lines/diff).

Comment: I used your approach, but I was not able to get the canvastOverlay working, I have asked a corresponding question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971088/using-jqplot-plugins-in-primefaces-charts-to-draw-lines-on-chart