# Using jqPlot plugins in PrimeFaces charts to draw lines on chart

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jqplot

I would like to draw some extra lines on my PrimeFaces (v5.3) chart, in particular on a linechart. Looking at the jqPlot example (PrimeFaces uses jqPlot to draw the charts), [this example](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/canvas-overlay.html) shows what I want to do.

I have used the approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562567/137369).

By setting an extender I am able to run my own javascript function,  which allows me to change different types of configuration.

Java when creating the mode:

```
private LineChartModel initLinearModel()
{
    LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();
    model.setExtender("chartExtender");

    LineChartSeries series1 = new LineChartSeries();
    series1.setLabel("Series 1");
    series1.set(1, 2);
    series1.set(2, 1);
    series1.set(3, 3);
    series1.set(4, 6);
    series1.set(5, 8);

    model.addSeries(series1);

    return model;
}
```

Xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:outputScript library="jqplot-plugin"
    name="jqplot.canvasOverlay.min.js" />
<h:outputScript library="js" name="extra_config.js" />

<h:head>
    <title>Chart</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <p:chart type="line" model="#{primeChart.lineModel1}"
        style="height:300px;" />

</h:body>

</html>
```

Javascript function:

```
function chartExtender() {
    this.cfg.grid = {
         background : '#888888',
    }
    this.cfg.canvasOverlay = {
            show: true,
            objects: [{horizontalLine: {
                        name: 'pebbles',
                        y: 3,
                        lineWidth: 2,
                        color: 'rgb(255, 55, 124)',
                        shadow: true,
                        lineCap: 'butt',
                        xOffset: 0
                    }}]
        };

}
```

The javascript function is being called, as the background is actually changed  But I see no changes I try to use the canvas overlay. Here is the output of the example:
[image: Output of this example]

I understand the jqPlot version that comes with PrimeFaces does not include the overlay plugin. So I have downloaded the latest jqPlot release and included the overlay plugin in my script (it is being included by JSF). But I might have very well missed something, or be taking the right approach when using this plugin.

The firefox webconsole reports it is missing jquery. I have also tried to include `jquery.min.js` and `jquery.jqplot.min.js` (from the jqplot release), this removed the error, but does not show the horizontal line.

How do I include a jqplot plugin? How can I further debug this situation to see what is going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your concrete problem is caused by incorrect ordering of JavaScript resources which should already be hinted by those JS errors complaining jQuery couldn't be found and incorrect `<script>` ordering in generated HTML output as you could see via rightclick *View Source* in webbrowser. Basically, you loaded the jqPlot script *before* jQuery and PrimeFaces scripts by misplacing the `<h:outputScript>` before `<h:head>`.

If you move the `<h:outputScript>` *inside* `<h:body>` with a `target="head"` like below ...

```
<h:head>
    <title>Chart</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript library="jqplot-plugin" name="jqplot.canvasOverlay.min.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="extra_config.js" target="head" />

    <p:chart type="line" model="#{primeChart.lineModel1}" style="height:300px;" />
</h:body>
```

... then magic will start to work.

[image]

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)
- [How to use jQuery and jQuery plugins with PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112058/how-to-use-jquery-and-jquery-plugins-with-primefaces/)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, `library="js"` is a bad practice. Carefully read [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used) what exactly it means and how it should be used (quick answer: get rid of it and use `name="js/extra_config.js"`).